# Emdoor EM TS809 Dead Boot - KCOLO point wanted to revive

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, unbricking, device-firmware

Flashing with a bad firmware to this tablet became completely unresponsive and does not switch on. M/B marks report that is created from **Emdoor** and its model is **EM TS809**.

https://www.globalsources.com/Voice-activated-speaker/MT8167-EM-TS809_R70-1173578814p.htm#1173578814

I tried to revive it, by shorting GND and KCOLO joints and reflashing with *SP Tools*. Unfortunately, joints do not have descriptions so I tried every joint without voltage. None of them worked. Does anyone know if this M/B has KCOLO or just COLO/KOLO joint?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, I'll just want to let you know that while this device is running Android, the core of the question looks more like an electrical engineering question than an Android one. While this community has a broad knowledge of the Android system, I'm not even sure they know about the detail of the underlying hardware, like a motherboard and its joint...

Comment: I suppose you have right, a member of this forum purposed to search for this solution

Comment: look for kpcol0 at page 7 (AA2) https://www.pigworld.pw/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/PCB-Design-Guidelines-for-MT8167.pdf kp=keypad col=column (n)=0 https://patents.google.com/patent/US20130162452

Comment: @alecxs thanks  alecxs, I will check it and I will let you know.

Comment: @alecs I just saw the PCB of the MT8167. Are you suggesting finding the pin of the KPCOL0 and Grounding it? If yes, this will be a little bit tricky since the IC has BGA  packaging, and it's pretty difficult to find the correct pin, but I will give it a try.

Comment: i suggest to follow the printed circuit track to some test point. of course it's tricky guesswork, but maybe it works the opposite way and you can track it down to the right corner of cpu (AA2), at least :)

Comment: @alecxs thanks I will do it !

Comment: I will give it a try :-)